# Bootstrap modal restores button focus on close

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in very difficult struggle with one effect, which I believe is wanted in Bootstrap, but I want to escape. I have button:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Video<i class="pe-7s-angle-right pe-2x pe-va" style="line-height: 0.3;"></i></a>
```

Which opens modal window with some video:

```
<div class="modal fade video-lightbox in" id="video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 442px;"></div>
```

So when I close the modal, my button gets in focus automatically. Is this effect wanted in Bootstrap and how can I escape it ? I don`t want my button to be in focus after closing the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by removing

```
d.trigger("focus")
```

in bootstrap.min.js:

```
a.fn.modal = b, a.fn.modal.Constructor = c, a.fn.modal.noConflict = function() {
    return a.fn.modal = d, this
}, a(document).on("click.bs.modal.data-api", '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(c) {
    var d = a(this),
        e = d.attr("href"),
        f = a(d.attr("data-target") || e && e.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, "")),
        g = f.data("bs.modal") ? "toggle" : a.extend({
            remote: !/#/.test(e) && e
        }, f.data(), d.data());
    d.is("a") && c.preventDefault(), f.one("show.bs.modal", function(a) {
        a.isDefaultPrevented() || f.one("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
            d.is(":visible") && d.trigger("focus")
        })
    }), b.call(f, g, this)
})
```

Comment: I am surprised that this is still an issue and this answer definitely works after none of the other answers worked. This also works for bootstrap 4 modal.

Comment: I don't want to change it bootstrap js file, because:
1. Its not a good practice
2. I want it on a particular modal box only.

does anyone got other solution?

Answer (score 9):

Blur buttons when modal closes.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $('.btn').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method, to make the modal-trigger loose focus when you close the modal:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#modalTrigger').one('focus', function (e) {
        $(this).blur();
    });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#modalTrigger').one('focus', function (e) {
            $(this).blur();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="modalTrigger" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write a function into your custom.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close')on("click", function() {
        $(".btn").blur();
    });
});
```

Comment: This wont work if the person clicks outside the modal to close it.

Answer (score 1):

By default in Bootstrap link or button gets focus after closing modal. You can escape it with this code:

```
$('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
    event.relatedTarget.blur();
});
```

Comment: Can you please describe what's being done with your code? Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to reference the event to find the relatedTarget:
`$('#mymodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
   event.relatedTarget.blur();
}); `