# How to remove focus from a button after botstrap modal closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on a button that launches bootstrap modal, and then close the modal, the button is still in focus. How to change it.

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#mymodal">Click me</a>
```

The modal has just one button "OK", I've tried to write a jquery function:

```
 function unfocus() {
     $('*:focus').blur();
 }
```

and the button then goes like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="unfocus()">OK</button>
```

but the focus remains on "Click me". How to remove it?

Comment: Why not `focus` on the `document`? I have a feeling since `:focus` selector is just a pseudo, it's deferring to the main element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be kind of a hack, but if you just an id to your link, say modalLink, you could try the following:

```
$('#modalLink').on({
    focus: function () {
        $(this).blur();
    }
});
```

I think that that will just remove the focus whenever the focus is set, which might be OK in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add and id to your button and modal and use the On event

```
$("#submitbutton_id").on('click', function () {
  if(! $("#modal_id").hasClass('in') ) {
    $("#your_element").blur();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is by design in Bootstrap, you might want to read this post, although there must be a better way than editing the bootstrap js.  I tried the other solution and that did not seem to work, maybe the bootstrap js overrides it somehow ?

[bootstrap-modal-restores-button-focus-on-close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322918/bootstrap-modal-restores-button-focus-on-close)